# Quarkus maven build from within Intellij, non-meaningful error log

Tags: intellij-idea, quarkus

When I run a maven build in Intellij in combination with the `quarkus-maven-plugin`, I often get a non-meaningfull compilaton error instead of a nice compilation error. I use the maven menu in Intellij to run the clean-install tasks.

This is the failure I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\xyz\Development\source\bro\registerbeheer-be -Djansi.passthrough=true "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63700:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2022.3.2 io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.2.Final:dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< nl.bro.microservices:rba-backend >------------------
[INFO] Building BRO - RBA2 - BACKEND 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.2.Final:dev (default-cli) @ rba-backend ---
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources) @ rba-backend
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 20 resources
[INFO] Invoking io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.11.2.Final:generate-code) @ rba-backend
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/nl/bro/microservices/rba-backend/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (3.2 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi-2.11.2.Final.pom (884 B at 5.0 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (2.1 kB at 13 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (2.7 kB at 14 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-security-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-security-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-security-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-security-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (2.5 kB at 13 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (3.3 kB at 21 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (2.0 kB at 13 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (3.3 kB at 21 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment-2.11.2.Final.pom (2.1 kB at 13 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-spi-2.11.2.Final.jar (3.5 kB at 7.1 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-validator-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (21 kB at 101 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-resteasy-multipart-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (4.4 kB at 27 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-security-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-security-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-security-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-security-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (31 kB at 140 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-reactive-routes-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (69 kB at 202 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (4.8 kB at 28 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-smallrye-jwt-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (11 kB at 63 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-common-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (7.2 kB at 41 kB/s)
Downloading from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar
Downloaded from nexus: http://gdnnexus01.gdnnet.lan/content/groups/broservices.group/io/quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment/2.11.2.Final/quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-deployment-2.11.2.Final.jar (11 kB at 65 kB/s)
[INFO] Invoking org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile) @ rba-backend
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 119 source files to C:\Users\xyz\Development\source\bro\registerbeheer-be\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  13.322 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-03T20:59:21+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/conf/logging/
constituent[1]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/cdi-api-1.0.jar
constituent[2]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar
constituent[3]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar
constituent[4]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
constituent[5]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guava-25.1-android.jar
constituent[6]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/guice-4.2.1-no_aop.jar
constituent[7]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jansi-1.17.1.jar
constituent[8]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
constituent[9]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.29.jar
constituent[10]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[11]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
constituent[12]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-artifact-3.8.1.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.8.1.jar
constituent[13]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-builder-support-3.8.1.jar
constituent[14]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-compat-3.8.1.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.8.1.jar
constituent[15]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-core-3.8.1.jar
constituent[16]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-embedder-3.8.1.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.8.1.jar
constituent[17]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-3.8.1.jar
constituent[18]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-model-builder-3.8.1.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.8.1.jar
constituent[19]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.8.1.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.1.jar
constituent[20]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.8.1.jar
constituent[21]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.6.2.jar
constituent[22]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.6.2.jar
constituent[23]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.6.2.jar
constituent[24]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.8.1.jar
constituent[25]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.6.2.jar
constituent[26]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-transport-wagon-1.6.2.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.6.2.jar
constituent[27]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.6.2.jar
constituent[28]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-3.8.1.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.8.1.jar
constituent[29]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.8.1.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[30]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-shared-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[31]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/maven-slf4j-provider-3.8.1.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
constituent[32]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.4.jar
constituent[33]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.4.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[34]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
constituent[35]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-component-annotations-2.1.0.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
constituent[36]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar
constituent[37]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[38]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.1.jar
constituent[39]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
constituent[40]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-file-3.4.3.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.4.3.jar
constituent[42]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/wagon-provider-api-3.4.3.jar
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:155)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.check(Assert.java:46)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Modules.enter(Modules.java:247)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.readSourceFile(JavaCompiler.java:837)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ImplicitCompleter.complete(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1521)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:642)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1326)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1140)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.complete(Type.java:1140)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.getTypeArguments(Type.java:1066)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:237)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visitClassType(Printer.java:52)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:993)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Printer.visit(Printer.java:136)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:199)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
constituent[41]: file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202022.3.2/plugins/maven/libFormatter.java:67)
ttp-3.4.3-shaded.jar
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArgument(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:185)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.formatArguments(AbstractDiagnosticFormatter.java:167)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:111)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.BasicDiagnosticFormatter.formatMessage(BasicDiagnosticFormatter.java:67)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util.JCDiagnostic.getMessage(JCDiagnostic.java:788)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$DiagnosticSourceUnwrapper.getMessage(ClientCodeWrapper.java:799)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:130)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:886)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.maven.DevMojo.executeIfConfigured(DevMojo.java:620)
    at io.quarkus.maven.DevMojo.triggerCompile(DevMojo.java:596)
    at io.quarkus.maven.DevMojo.handleAutoCompile(DevMojo.java:551)
    at io.quarkus.maven.DevMojo.execute(DevMojo.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

There's no line to which to refer to.

Running the build from within the Intelij build-menu  gives the proper results.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see clean-install task under maven menu ?

Comment: Could you post full log of maven command please ? there may be hints earlier in the build process

Comment: of course.. as soon as I see it occurring again I'll add those details.. Cannot reproduce atm. Tnx

Comment: complete trace added